# Need help on apache2 permissions

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

It's been two days now without a solution, so I'm asking for help. I've searched and tried, I solved a few problems already but there is one last thing.

This is what I'm trying to do: change the default directory of apache2 from /var/www/html to /media/pi/storage/root_folder/

I have followed this tutorial > https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Virtual_Hosts

under section virtual hosts, I created a test html at /home/pi/Desktop/ and it works because of (I assume) correct permissions.

Now when I do the exact same thing at /media/pi/storage/root_folder/ and reload the webpage, I get forbidden error message, suggesting that I have permission (again, I assume this is right) issues on my hard drive (which is formatted with ext4)

Will something like this work?
`sudo chown -R USER:USER /media/pi/storage/root_folder/` OR `chgrp -R www-data /username/` `chmod -R 2750 /username/` OR it's something else?

I don't know what command is needed, a step-by-step would be greatly appreciated

And finally, how do I get these permissions to be applied for any new subdirectories and files in the future so that I don't run into the same forbidden error ever again?

I appreciate any help, thanks guys..

The virtual host configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /media/pi/storage/root_folder/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Apache error log snippet:

```
[Sun Dec 17 05:29:33.304748 2017] [core:error] [pid 951:tid 1836053552] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.1.137:43006] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/media/pi/storage') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Output of `ls -ld /media /media/pi /media/pi/storage`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Nov 29 02:57 /media
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root 4096 Dec 17 05:28 /media/pi
drwxr-xr-x  4 pi   pi   4096 Dec 16 20:31 /media/pi/storage
```

Comment: @J.Starnes The text in the images is not relevant anyway, I'll just remove them.

Comment: @fkraiem Very well, the comment was meant to encourage the op to understand the encouraged practices.

Comment: ok, won't do it again in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also allow Apache to access that directory. By default, Apache is only allowed to access `/var/www` and `/usr/share`; this access is granted by blocks like this in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Thus you must add a similar block somewhere in your Apache configuration, to grant access to `/media/pi/storage/root_folder/`:

```
<Directory /media/pi/storage/root_folder/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If you already have a `<Directory /media/pi/storage/root_folder/>` block, for example in your virtual host config file, just adding the `Require all granted` directive to it will be sufficient.

In addition, the error log shows that Apache (*i.e.*, the `www-data` user) does not have read or search permissions to a component of `/media/pi/storage`. The output of `ls -ld /media /media/pi /media/pi/storage` shows that `/media` and `/media/pi/storage` both have 755 permissions, so the culprit must be `/media/pi`. Since `/media/pi` is using [Access Control Lists](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-acls.html) (as denoted by the `+` sign in the output of `ls -ld`), we give `www-data` read and search permissions with

```
sudo setfacl -m u:www-data:rx /media/pi
```

Comment: I need to first install acl.. EDIT: That worked ! Ok, now to reboot and see if it persists

Comment: ok, works after a reboot, the index.html is served but when I click on a link, it says file not found, i've double checked the file path and it is correct. It says > `/virtual tours/2nd place/2nd.html was not found on this server.` the virtual tours does not have a space on my drive, it is virtual_tours with an underscore. Why is apache not getting that?                           EDIT: My full path is > /media/pi/storage/root_folder/virtual_tours/2nd place/2nd.html but it seems that when I click on the link, apache is getting virtual tours (without the underscore)

Comment: @johndoe666 That probably should be a different question. If the permission issue is solved, please accept the answer, and then post a new question about the link issue.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, my html code was wrong. I can solve that myself. Thank you very very much sir ! Many many many thanks to you, this has been bothering me for the past two days. haha, now it's solved !

Comment: Final note, this solution could help quite a few people out there who are facing a similar issue, after all, this is a commonly asked question, is there a way to share this solution to others in the future?

Comment: If someone asks a similar question in the future, the community may mark it as a duplicate of this. It will also appear in search results of course.